# Rectangular blocks appear when I start emacs

Tags: spacemacs

So this is happening from past few days.
When I start Emacs it is displaying rectangular block for each character. 
[image]

and when I start Emacs inside the terminal with the -nw option it starts renders fine inside the terminal. 
`emacs -nw`

[image]

Not sure of what might be wrong?

Comment: What Emacs/Spacemacs is that? Please specify just what you are using and how you are using it. Do you see the same problem when you start Emacs using `emacs -Q`? If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: Thanks for the small review/suggestion. I am using Emacs 25 with the latest spacemacs configuration. I apparently solved the issue. Adding an answer for that.

Answer (score 4):

**What went wrong ?**

A recent script for installing fonts in the `i3wm-themer` uninstalled the fonts which were being used by my current Emacs configuration. So Emacs was not being able to find those fonts and was displaying the rectangular blocks.

The font configuration was specified in my `.spacemacs` config file

```
  dotspacemacs-default-font '("Source Code Pro"
                           :size 13
                           :weight normal
                           :width normal
                           :powerline-scale 1.1)
```

**How I fixed it?**

I changed the fonts to an available font such as `Monospace` and restarted Emacs.

```
   dotspacemacs-default-font '("Monospace"
                               :size 13
                               :weight normal
                               :width normal
                               :powerline-scale 1.1)
```

This solved the issue. 
While solving this I also learned about the `M-x menu-set-font` which helped me set my fonts using a font selection GUI menu.

References:

1. [Github Issue with similar problems](https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-code-pro/issues/17#issuecomment-223753308)
2. [Set Fonts tutorial on Emacs Wiki](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/SetFonts)